# How can I insert a binary file > 4GB into oracle blob?

Tags: oracle, blob, large-files, sqldatatypes

How can I insert a binary file > 4GB into oracle blob?

Oracle documentation says Maximum BLOB size: (4 GB - 1) * DB_BLOCK_SIZE
I have oracle 11g installation with DB_BLOCK_SIZE = 8kb

Still I am not able to insert a 5GB file here, but successfully able to insert 3.9 GB file.

Comment: How are you inserting? It might help to show your code. What error do you get? What version are you using?

Comment: It is dependent upon OS and version, what OS are you using?

Comment: I am using oracle 11g on windows 7 64 bit machine.

Answer (score 0):

If your specific version doesn't allows it: you can't. But you can Split a Binary File into Multiple Chunks and then load them one by one. I personally avoid loading big binary files into Oracle, just keeping reference on them. Except backup issue it might be no other advantages to keep binary files in DB and not on file system. The disadvantage is huge: you generating many archive log files during load.